# Convert uploaded picture to thumbnail picture + Blobstore

Tags: google-app-engine, thumbnails, picturebox, blobstore

**Questions:**

1. In Google App Engine Blobstore, is there a way to convert the original picture uploaded to thumbnail picture?
2. Is converting the picture to thumbnail picture a good idea or there are better ways?
3. What are the best optimization if I wish to use thumbnail picture as well as normal pictures? What I meant is that, shall I waste additional storage just to store the thumbnail pictures?

Performance is preferred very much. Thank you in advance for who's willing to help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to store additional thumbnail versions of pictures. Check out [get_serving_url()](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/functions.html).

You can use that function to generate a -public, but not guessable- URL to the picture with parameters to do resizing on the fly and it's optimized for performance. I think it's well suited for your needs.